# Harmonic Product Spectrum algorithm. I dont understand one step

Tags: sound, pitch, peak-detection

I was looking some Harmonic Product Spectrum algorithm examples and I came up with this:

```
//Implement Harmonic Product Spectrum
for(k = 0; k < buffer_size / 8; k++)
{
    sum[k] = magFFT[k] * magFFT[2*k] * magFFT[3*k];
    // find fundamental frequency (maximum value in plot)
    if( sum[k] > max_value2 && k > 0 )
    {
        max_value2 = sum[k];
        fund_freq = k;
    }
 }
 fund_freq1 = fund_freq * 8000 / buffer_size;
```

What I dont understand is the reason behind the last line, I tested it and it works but I couldn't find an explanation for that multiplication. Can anyone help me please?

Source of code: [SOURCE](https://fftguitartuner.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/ee113d-final-report2.pdf)

Comment: is your sampling rate 16 kHz or 8 kHz, by any chance?

Comment: It's 8kHz, you have any ideas?

Comment: Based on your reply to Marcus' comment, it converts the found DFT index $k$ into the analog frequency in Hertz for a hardwired(?) sampling frequency of 8000 Hz, where *buffersize* shall denote the DFT length $N$.

Comment: sorta interesting pitch detection algorithm.  it won't work right if there is a **missing fundamental** (but other odd harmonics are present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"8000 / buffer_size"  is frequency resolution, decide by  sample length or "buffer_size",

you know the sampling interval is "1/8000", the whole time length 'T' of the sequence is "buffer_size/8000", then '1/T' is frequency resolution,

in your code,if 'k' is 0, represent 0hz,is the signal's dc part,if 'k' is 1,represent '1/T' or "8000 / buffer_size" hz, then you can see 'k' correspond with frequency bin "k*8000 / buffer_size" .